# PHP, using Joomla, algorithm, networking if else,

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, if-statement, joomla

**Hi, I have a question, when i ever insert this code**

```
if ($pointsreach>=$tempunilevel ){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `incentives_table` SET pointsreach = pointsreach +500 where userid = '$newsponsorid' ");
```

**the  if statement does not work anymore**

```
if (count($items) >0 && $lev <= 10  ){ // found get sponsor id for the next computation             
    $sponsorid = $items->upline; //sponsor id
```

**but when i remove the**

```
if ($pointsreach>=$tempunilevel ){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `incentives_table` SET pointsreach = pointsreach +500 where userid = '$newsponsorid' ");
```

**the statement works perfectly ...**

```
$query = " UPDATE `#__eds_incentives_table` SET `temp` = `temp` + 25 where `userid` = '$sponsorid' ";
    $db->setQuery($query);  
    $db->query();

    $mote = $this->entryuni($sponsorid, $lev + 1, +25);
}
else {
    return 'ok';
}
```

**This is the code**

```
public function entryuni($newsponsorid = null, $lev = 2, $fpv = 0)
{
    $db = & JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT upline,fslot FROM `table` where userid = '$newsponsorid' ";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $items = $db->loadObject();
    $items = (!empty($items)) ? $items : array();

    $queryreach  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM incentives_table WHERE userid = '$newsponsorid' ");
    $fetchreach = mysql_fetch_array($queryreach);
    $pointsreach=$fetchreach['pointsreach'];
    $tempunilevel=$fetchreach['temp_unilevel'];

    if ($pointsreach>=$tempunilevel ){
        mysql_query("UPDATE `incentives_table` SET pointsreach = pointsreach +500 where userid = '$newsponsorid' ");

        if (count($items) >0 && $lev <= 10  ){ // found get sponsor id for the next computation
            $sponsorid = $items->upline; //sponsor id
            $query = " UPDATE `#__eds_incentives_table` SET `temp` = `temp` + 25 where `userid` = '$sponsorid' ";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();

            $mote = $this->entryuni($sponsorid, $lev + 1, +25);
        }
        else {
            return 'ok';
        }
```

Comment: seems obvious that `$pointsreach>=$tempunilevel` isn't true. Why do you have insecure and deprecated `mysql_query`'s mixed with far safer and more secure joomla $db queries?

Comment: I m voting to close this question!!